# Ansible, counting occurence of a word in a string

Tags: ansible

I am fairly new to Ansible, and I have been googling about this particular issue described below:

```
name: GETTING OUTPUT AND STORING IT INTO A VARIABLE
  connection: network_cli
  cli_command:
    command: show configuration interface ge-0/0/0  | display set | match unit
  register: A
```

Above, the task will run the command `show configuration interface ge-0/0/0` on Juniper router, the out put will contain a bunch of key words `unit`. This output is then stored in a variable A.

I want to count the number of occurence key word `unit` appear in the output  and store it in a variable COUNT. How can I do that? Ijust need an example.

Thanks and have a good weekend!!

Comment: Isn't the answer simply going to be the number of lines returned by the command?

Comment: It looks like it is not:     "A.stdout_lines": [
        "show configuration interfaces ge-0/0/1 \u0007| display set | match family ",
        "set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet address 199.199.199.1/24",
        "set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet address 200.200.200.1/24"   so I see three lines returned , instead of two,

Comment: Okay, so `(A.stdout_lines|length)-1`, then?

Comment: Appreciated the help, now , it is giving me the right number of lines i.e  2, but how do i store this 2 into a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this task:

```
- name: get output and store
  connection: network_cli
  cli_command:
    command: show configuration interface ge-0/0/0  | display set | match unit
  register: show_config_result
```

Then you use a subsequent [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) task to store the value you want in a variable:

```
- name: store unit count in unit_count variable
  set_fact:
    unit_count: "{{ (show_config_result.stdout_lines|length)-1 }}"
```